# Why are FontAwesome icons inflating in size?

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am using FontAwesome in an embeddable Web data visualization component. So, a package of css, html, and js that a third party can embed in their website.

Everything works correctly except fontawesome icon sizes are inflated in size. Is this due to the client having their own css for the `i` html element or is there something else going on?

### UPDATE

Some typical use of fa: `<i class="igv-app-icon fa fa-minus-square-o fa-2x" style="padding-right: 4px;">`

Comment: what do you mean by inflating in size ? can you share a screenshot or some code so we can see how you assigned your data. If you have responsive text that's the only thing I could think of that would cause the icons to grow in size.

Comment: Paul, here is a typical use of fa in my code `<i class="igv-app-icon fa fa-minus-square-o fa-2x" style="padding-right: 4px;">`. Much larger in my clients web app then our inhouse test web app.

Comment: Other than font-size only thing I could think of is screen resolution your client could be zoomed in ? Any chance this is a public app that we can look at?
Have you tried reducing the padding

Comment: Hang on, what I should have asked: is there any way to disable any other class associations to `i` and `font-size` within the borders of my component?

Comment: You can, just assign the classes without the i tag to a span, prior to doing that I would try to change the font size on that particular icon, assign it an ID and see how it changes.

Comment: Ok, so Paul is the most helpful but hasn't suggested an actual answer. Paul, just repeat the bit about `font-size` and `i` and I will give you this one.

Comment: thank you, I submitted a  response @dugla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have responsive text that's the only thing I could think of that would cause the icons to grow in size.

I would try to change the font size on that particular icon, assign it an ID and see how it changes.

Alternatively if the i tag is the issue, you can just assign the classes without the i tag to a span.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of custom css for `i` element or the `.icon` class. Please include the reference to the site so it can be investigated.

**UPDATE**:

1. Try removing the `fa-2x` class.
2. If that doesn't work, inspect the element from a browser and check the font-size in the computed styles tab to see what size is being applied and where it's being applied.

Comment: Should make this a comment for future references as we are requesting more information from the user.

Comment: Sadly, the client site is behind a VPN'd firewall.

Comment: @dugla In that case you could inspect the icon element in browser and go to the Computed Styles and check the font-size to see what's being applied. Also i see you're using `fa-2x` class from your comment above. try removing the class.

Comment: So whats wrong with `fa-2x`? Or any other fa size manipulation classes?

Comment: @dugla `fa-2x` doubles the normal font-size of the icon. Please see: [font-awesome larger icons](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Liam thanks yeah i don't have sufficient reputation that's why commenting on my own posts.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble using fontawesome in `<i>` you can try to use it in a `<span>` or any other element that fits better in your project.

Comment: i have seen a few problems related to the use of `em` in font-size, like `font-size:1em`.   
  
Since the `em` default size can be modified in the css, maybe this is messing your code.